# Code works in R but nor in RStudio

Tags: r, statistics

I loaded the csv file "WHO.csv". There are some missing data in the column 'GNI' which displays "NA". In RGui, when I execute the command "WHO$GNI", the data shown is normal. But in RStudio, it attaches "\r(data)\r" to each data, which is wierd. This results in RStudio's inability to identify max or min in that column, even if NA is removed. Pictures of execution are in the links below. How can I fix this?? Thank you for your time.
[Execution in R](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPhnr.png)

[Execution in RStudio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJEkr.png)

Comment: `WHO$GNI <- as.numeric(gsub("\\D+", "", WHO$GNI))` this will remove all non numbers (i'm assuming that there is no decimal point) and convert it to a numeric vector.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
WHO$GNI <-  gsub("\r", "", WHO$GNI)
WHO$GNI <- as.numeric(WHO$GNI)
```

As `\r` is the carriage return character, this behaviour is probably because of your `.csv` file. I'm not sure why RGui and RStudio acting different.

*Edit: Vectorized gsub.*

Comment: `gsub` can be vectorized so you don't need `lapply`. Also I suspect the code breaks the structure of the data.frame as the return from `lapply` is a list.